# Compare changes between two branches in vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Let say I am on branch `side-branch`, and did some changes. I can see the changes in vscode by clicking on the left `Source Control` button.

If I switch to other branch I have to stash it so that If I switch back and apply I can still see what I changed.

It works for me a lot of times but sometimes I need to commit the changes in order to prevent a long commit (having more changes).

But now I lost the option to compare the change.

I tried using `git diff develop` while I am on `side-branch` but It uses built in console to show the diffs.

I tried using below command `git config --global diff.tool vscode` it does not work. I am using mac.

I would be nice If I could compare the changes like I could when I didn't commmit. Is there any option?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I am using two combined extensions for now to start with.

1. GitLense
2. Git Graph